# How to load object relations that both exist and don't exist in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 2 models: Comment and ReadReceipt. A Comment has many ReadReceipt for a given User. I want to create an ActiveRecord relation that would allow me Return all Comments with their ReadReceipt even if it doesn't exist. For example,

```
comments = Comment.includes(:read_receipts).all
comments.first.read_receipt -> #<ReadReceipt id: 1>
comments.last.read_receipt -> nil
```

Currently I have this #read_receipt on Comment. However, as I want to avoid N+1 queries I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. Do I need to do an left outer join? What's the Rails way to achieve this?

```
def read_receipt(user)
  receipt = ReadReceipt.find_by(feed_item_id: id, contact_id: user.contact.id)
  receipt ? true : false
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume your join column is `feed_item_id` in `ReadReceipt`.

For Rails 4, use `includes` and do *LEFT OUTER JOIN* manually, this will save you from N+1 queries and will also give all those comments where read receipt doesn't exist:

```
comments = Comment.includes(:read_receipts).joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN read_receipts on read_receipts.feed_item_id = comments.id')

comments.map do |c|
  c.read_receipt(some_user)
end
```

Because of `includes` earlier, read_receipts are already loaded in memory, using ActiveRecord for querying in `read_receipt` will run the query again with more parameters. You can use ruby instead if you want to get away with that. You can use [`loaded?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Association/loaded%3F) to check if association is loaded or not.

Change your `Comment#read_receipt` to:

```
def read_receipt(user)
  # this will not load read receipts again in memory or fire any other query with subparameters
  if read_receipts.loaded? # this means association is already loaded, use Ruby
    read_receipts.find { |r| r.feed_item_id == id && r.contact_id == user.contact_id } ? true : false
  else
    # do not load all read_receipts, instead use proper ActiveRecord
    read_receipts.find_by(contact_id: user.contact.id) ? true : false
  end
end
```

For Rails 5, use `left_outer_joins`:

```
comments = Comment.includes(:read_receipts).left_outer_joins(:read_receipts)
comments.map do |c|
  c.read_receipt(some_user)
end
```